# Dealing with ligatures using pdfminer in python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, pdfminer

I have a Python script which reads in the text from pdf documents using PDFminer like so:

```
def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    file_pointer = file(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(file_pointer, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password, caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    file_pointer.close()
    device.close()
    str = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return str
```

This appears to work well as the text shows up when this string, str, is printed. However, upon closer inspection there are a number of character doubles (namely "ff", "fi", "fl" and "ff") which turn into "! " when looking through the generated text.

After some research I found that these characters all have 'ligatures' which means they can be replaced with a joined version of the two characters.

These ligatures are obviously not able to be found in ASCII but I found that they are able to be represented through unicode.

I began experimenting with different character encodings in order to make the "! "s in my text turn into their correct ligatures but I have not been successful.

Perhaps this has to do with my PDF files or PDFminer itself?

Answer (score 6):

So I ended up emailing the creator of PDFMiner, Yusuke Shinyama. I have summarized his reply below.

- The PDF in question uses special fonts for ligatures.
- Letters like "fi" "ff" or "fl" are sometimes treated specially in English typography, and they are often combined into one glyph to make it look better.
- The PDF in question does exactly this, and uses "! " as the combined letter, which probably looks like "fi" or "ff" when rendered with that specialized font.
- Since PDFMiner doesn't have that information, it always try to extract the
  literal text in a document.

According to Dr Shinyama, there's no good solution to this, except maybe putting everything to an OCR software.

---

I didn't have time to implement OCR and so I have written a very simple spell checker instead. The spell checker runs through my text finding words with "! " (using regex) and then comparing them to a list of known words featuring ligatures.

According to Dr Shinyamas, there are still many PDFs like this in the world and converting a PDF into text always ends up with a "best effort" result.

Comment: Language is literally amazing. Thank you for this wonderfully insightful answer! Of course as a computer scientist it makes me scream internally, but as a human it gives me pause to consider the eclectic cultural mélange that is both the unicode standard and the greater internet.